# How do I set a true/false value with an addition query targeting a value in a second table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one for members and another one for their services. Those are InnoDB tables on MySQL 5.6 server.

members table:

```
id     |       name       |   phone
----------------------------------------
  1       Daniel             123456789
  2       Liam               123456789
  3       Lucas              123456789
```

services table:

```
 MID    |  category    |     lastSeen
----------------------------------------
  1       35                 2014-08-13 14:23:23
  3       35                 2014-08-12 15:29:11
  2       12                 2014-08-12 15:29:11
```

I try to achieve this result:

```
 id     | name      | services
---------------------------------
  1       Daniel      true
  2       Liam        false
  3       Lucas       true
```

The result would be based on whether or not members.id = services.MID and and true or false based on their services.category equaling '35'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `left join` and `case when` something as

```
select
m.id,
m.name,
case when s.MID is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as services
from members m
left join services s on s.MID = m.id and s.category = 35 ;
```